# How to make API call using axios in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have tried to call API using Axios in vue.js app, API called successfully but the value is not affected. I wanted to set value which returns from the API response.

[Sample URL](https://jsfiddle.net/jz1w6xLm/)

> Vue.js code

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      info: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
      .then(response => (this.info = response))
  }
})
```

> HTML code

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{ info }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed to include `axios`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      info: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
      .then(response => (this.info = response))
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{ info }}
</div>
```